# What questions should I prepare to answer and ask in an interview with the CEO?

Tags: interviewing

It has been many years since I have interviewed with the CEO of a tech company. It used to be standard practice in the field, but a lot has changed.

Anyway, what are some questions I can expect to be asked? What are some questions I should ask?

Comment: I doubt all tech companies are the same or all CEOs are the same. I have just as much of an idea what a random CEO of a random tech company might ask as you do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what are some questions I can expect to be asked? What are some
> questions I should ask?

It will almost certainly depend on the particular CEO, and the company's field of work.

The last time I interviewed with a CEO, I was asked a bunch of high-level questions regarding my domain (it was software QA), about my leadership style, about the companies where I worked in the past (the CEO knew of many of those companies and their leadership), and my goals.

In turn I asked about the company, their finances, and specifically the CEO's vision for my potential boss's role and authority. I was worried that my boss would not be granted the clout he needed to help turn the company around.

The motivation for interviewing with the CEO was mostly mine. I had turned down an offer from the hiring manager (with whom I had worked at a prior company) because I was worried that he wouldn't be able to turn the Engineering team around - the reason he was hired, and part of the reason they wanted me aboard. After the discussion with the CEO, I decided to give it a shot. I'm glad I did - we were indeed able to turn things around.

In general, expect high-level questions from the CEO. Ask questions about the company, and whatever high-level things you need answered for you to make your decision.

Comment: Out of curiosity, did you express your specific concern in that interview?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere, would you mind added an example or two of questions to ask?

Answer (score 1):

I would add to not waste the CEO's time.  Think of questions at a higher level (things that a CEO has to think of), and boil them down to a very few questions.